# How to extract a Key value pair from a field and group by in Splunk?

Tags: splunk

I have the following raw data in the below format and I want to extract roleName by userid

```
{
  "publish_time": 1646290477.425,
  "data": {
    "insertId": ".........0aYgxUnj.d8yODdMsq7ciQa",
    "jsonPayload": {
      "GUID": "9685fea6-4a6b-4487-b84f-389b31738981",
      "date": "[3/3/2022, 12:24:26 PM]",
      "hostname": "localhost",
      "level": 200,
      "message": "landingpage:{\"message\":\"Time to Load data\",\"operation\":\"performance\",\"marketName\":\"India\",\"roleName\":\"Lead\",\"logging.googleapis.com/operation\":{\"id\":\"performance\",\"startTime\":\"2022-03-03T06:54:25.948Z\",\"endTime\":\"2022-03-03T06:54:26.197Z\",\"duration\":249,\"logInfo\":\"load time\"}}",
      "msg": "",
      "name": "my-service",
      "origin": "UI Layer",
      "pid": 1,
      "service": "88888",
      "sessionstarttime": "2022-03-03T06:46:28.000Z",
      "severity": "INFO",
      "time": "Thu Mar 03 2022 06:54:26 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
      "userid": "zuri",
      "v": 0
    },
    "logName": "projects/7a4ad544/logs/bunyan_log",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2022-03-03T06:54:36.268350936Z",
    "resource": {
      "labels": {
        "function_name": "WriteLogMessage",
        "project_id": "7a4ad544",
        "region": "us-east1"
      },
      "type": "cloud_function"
    },
    "timestamp": "2022-03-03T06:54:26.756999969Z"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "logging.googleapis.com/timestamp": "2022-03-03T06:54:26.756999969Z"
  }
}
```

I want to extract roleName from data.jsonPayload.message field by data.jsonPayload.userid

Can someone please help. I tried rex field=data.jsonPayload.message "roleName:\s(?\d+)" but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the `spath` command is used to parse JSON, but it doesn't work on this input.  Instead, you can use `rex` on the _raw field to do the extractions.

```
| rex "\"userid\": \"(?<userid>[^\"]+)" 
| rex "\"roleName\":\"(?<roleName>[^\"]+)"
```